# How to validate the URL using regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I need to check if an URL is valid or not. The URL should contain some subdirectories like as:

```
example.com/test/test1/example/a.html
```

The URL should contain subdirectories `test`, `test1` and `example`. How can I check if the URL is valid using regex in Java?

Comment: So do you want to check wheter or not the URL is valid, or if it cotains test and test1?

Comment: yes...i thats correct...

Comment: What if it's `test%31` instead of `test1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to do in regex, how about this...

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("example\\.com/test/test1/example/[\\w\\W]*");

System.out.println("OK: " + p.matcher("example.com/test/test1/example/a.html").find());
System.out.println("KO: " + p.matcher("example.com/test/test2/example/a.html").find());
```

Comment: Might as well do `url.startsWith("example.com/test/test1/example/")` if that's all you're doing.

Comment: True... but for performance sake, it is better to precompile the pattern then reuse it again and again later on.

Comment: No, a compiled regex will still not be faster than String.startsWith(), since startsWith() always just matches the characters one by one, which is what the regular expression needs to do even in the optimal case. Also, your regular expression isn't anchored, and you are using .find(), so it would return true even if the URL was http://my.evil.domain/doBadStuff?url=example.com/test/test2/example/a.html

Answer (score 2):

```
String url = "example.com/test/test1/example/a.html";
List<String> parts = Arrays.asList(url.split("/"));
return (parts.contains("test") && parts.contains("test1") && parts.contains("example"));
```

Comment: You can get rid of `? true : false`. It's superfluous, the expression already returns a `boolean` anyway :)

Comment: What about `example.com/nope.html?query=lol/test/test1/example/lol`?

Comment: @poly: good one, replace `url.split("/")` by `url.split("\\?", 2)[0].split("/")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass your URL as an argument to the `java.net.URL(String)` constructor and check if the constructor throws `java.net.MalformedURLException`.

**EDIT** If, however, you simply want to check if a given string contains a given substring, use the `String.contains(CharSequence)` method.  For example:

```
String url = "example.com/test/test1/example/a.html";
if (url.contains("/test/test1/")) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: i mean the given url should contain certain directories not an valid url sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered here using regular expressions:
[Regular expression to match URLs in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163360/regular-expresion-to-match-urls-java)

But you can use the library **Apache Commons Validators** to use some tested validators instead to write your own.

Here is the library:
http://commons.apache.org/validator/

And here the javadoc of the URL Validator.
http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/UrlValidator.html