# Can I get position of specific link in webview?

Tags: android, url, webview, position, touch

[image]

I want to touch to specific url using code.

Information is only url.

If I can get position of this url, it will be very easy.

Can I get coordinate of url, or is there a better way?

(I can send touch event using code and I can get html source of viewing page from webview.)

Answer (score 0):

Now initially I thought you just wanted to click on the link so I posted the code snippet. But since you are asking for getting the position I haven't seen any api that does that for you to provide you the position of the links.

However you can try the the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814844/get-all-url-in-webview-when-page-loads).

Basically loading a page in HttpUrlConnection and extracting its html and then running it through the regex would be the way to go.