# How can I extract all links (href) in an HTML file?

Tags: java, href

I am trying to extract all links from an HTML file using Java.

The pattern seems to be `<a href = "Name">`.
I would like to obtain the URL that would enable me to access the desired webpage.

Can you guys help me out with an approach (string.contains? string.indexof?)?

Thank you.

Comment: Use parser like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). This way you can just call `document.select("a")` and get all links. Also visit http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax for more info about select syntax to specify what can appear in `href` attribute.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract links from a web page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120171/extract-links-from-a-web-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A basic fundamentals approach would be to use regex matching.

```
    String html = "YOUR HTML";
    String regex = "<a href\\s?=\\s?\"([^\"]+)\">";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);
    int index = 0;
    while (matcher.find(index)) {
        String wholething = matcher.group(); // includes "<a href" and ">"
        String link = matcher.group(1); // just the link
        // do something with wholething or link.
        index = matcher.end();
    }
```

On the other hand, you could use something like `Document`. I don't know much about this.