# Android - Button disabled until a valid URL is entered in edittext

Tags: android, url, button

I am trying to create a screen which has an `EditText` where an url needs to be entered and a `Verify` button which will be highlighted when a valid url is entered.

I wanted to know what is the logic to find whether a url entered is valid or not? Should I look for `.com` string in the edittext or is there any other logic? and How can I get the text as and when user enters a character so that the button gets highlighted as soon as a valid url is entered.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Url validation: [Regular expression to match URLs in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163360/regular-expresion-to-match-urls-java)
2. How to enable button just when user enters a valid URL:

Let's guess your `EditText` has the `txt_url` id:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_url);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        // lets supouse validation method is called validUrl()
        button.setEnabled(validUrl(editable.toString()));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UrlValidator validator = new UrlValidator();
validator.validate(url);
```

I think `validator.validate` is a boolean, but I'm not sure...

With that you culd then invoke the `setVisible(true/false)` of the button.

Comment: `UrlValidator` belongs to the Apache's Commons Validator package which is not included by default in Android.

Comment: Good to know about UrlValidator. Thanks for the response. However, Cristian's response is more complete.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a URL object and catch the MalformedURLException, like this:

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {  
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(String.valueOf(s));
                // code to show verify button here
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // show not verified here
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This also validates URL's like http://localhost/ which may not be *valid* for some apps. It is nice though... I like it.