# Regular expression to remove jsessionid from the URL using java

Tags: java

I need to remove the jsessionid from the given URL .The jessionid is not in the query part
for example i have URL like

```
http://example.com/index.do;jsessionid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX?username=example
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are you new to regex?

Comment: yes i followed this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163360/regular-expresion-to-match-urls-java

Comment: That thread is overkill for your purposes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
url = url.replaceAll(";jsessionid=[^?]*", "");
```

This will work whether or not your url has any parameters, eg, it will work for both of these:

- `http://example.com/index.do;jsessionid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`
- `http://example.com/index.do;jsessionid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX?username=example`

It employs a regex "look ahead" to capture up to (but not including) either a `?` or end of input.

Comment: Maybe a simpler version like ";jsessionid=[0-9A-Za-z]*" should be enough ?

Comment: @morellet.d actually it can even simpler:  `url = url.replaceAll(";jsessionid=[^?]*", "");`