# In java, what's the best way to read a url and split it into its parts?

Tags: java, string, url, split

Firstly, I am aware that there are other posts similar, but since mine is using a URL and I am not always sure what my delimiter will be, I feel that I am alright posting my question. My assignment is to make a crude web browser. I have a textField that a user enters the desired URL into. I then have obviously have to navigate to that webpage. Here is an example from my teacher of what my code would look kinda like. This is the code i'm suposed to be sending to my socket. Sample url: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

```
 GET /wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol HTTP/1.1\n
Host: en.wikipedia.org\n
\n
```

So my question is this: I am going to read in the url as just one complete string, so how do I extract just the "en.wikipedia.org" part and just the extension? I tried this as a test:

```
 String url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext Transfer Protocol";
    String done = " ";
    String[] hope = url.split(".org");

    for ( int i = 0; i < hope.length; i++)
    {
        done = done + hope[i];
    }
    System.out.println(done);
```

This just prints out the URL without the ".org" in it. I think i'm on the right track. I am just not sure. Also, I know that websites can have different endings (.org, .com, .edu, etc) so I am assuming i'll have to have a few if statements that compenstate for the possible different endings. Basically, how do I get the url into the two parts that I need?

Comment: Some answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection are applicable as well

Answer (score 46):

The [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class pretty much does this, look at the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html). For example, given this URL:

```
http://example.com:80/docs/books/tutorial/index.html?name=networking#DOWNLOADING
```

This is the kind of information you can expect to obtain:

```
protocol = http
authority = example.com:80
host = example.com
port = 80
path = /docs/books/tutorial/index.html
query = name=networking
filename = /docs/books/tutorial/index.html?name=networking
ref = DOWNLOADING
```

Comment: awesome! thanks. I really need to get to know my Classes better

Comment: @GabrielleLee you're welcome! if this answer was helpful for you, please don't forget to accept it by clicking on the check mark to its left ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should split your URL parts: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `url.split(".org");` try `url.split("/");` and iterate through your array of strings.

Or you can look into regular expressions. [This is a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163360/regular-expresion-to-match-urls-in-java) to start with.

Good luck on your homework.

Comment: Use the specifically designed URL. It will handle many edge cases that are difficult with simple split, or regex.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the answer with [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class is great, here is one more way to split URL to components using REGEXP:

```
"^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?"
      ||            |  |          |       |   |        | |
      12 - scheme   |  |          |       |   |        | |
                    3  4 - authority, includes hostname/ip and port number.
                                  5 - path|   |        | |
                                          6   7 - query| |
                                                       8 9 - fragment
```

You can use it with [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class:

```
var regex = "^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?";
var pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
var matcher = pattern.matcher("http://example.com:80/docs/books/tutorial/index.html?name=networking#DOWNLOADING");
if (matcher.matches()) {
  System.out.println("scheme: " + matcher.group(2));
  System.out.println("authority: " + matcher.group(4));
  System.out.println("path: " + matcher.group(5));
  System.out.println("query: " + matcher.group(7));
  System.out.println("fragment: " + matcher.group(9));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use String class `split()` and store the result into the String array then iterate the array and store the variable and value into the Map.

```
public class URLSPlit {
    public static Map<String,String> splitString(String s) {
        String[] split = s.split("[= & ?]+");
        int length = split.length;
        Map<String, String> maps = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i=0; i<length; i+=2){
              maps.put(split[i], split[i+1]);
        }

        return maps;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String word = "q=java+online+compiler&rlz=1C1GCEA_enIN816IN816&oq=java+online+compiler&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.18920j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8?k1=v1";
        Map<String, String> newmap =  splitString(word);

        for(Map.Entry map: newmap.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(map.getKey()+"  =  "+map.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the specifically designed URL. It will handle many edge cases that are difficult with simple split, or regex.