# Java replaceAll use found pattern in replacement

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace all links on a HTML page with a defined URL and the original link in the query string.

Here is an example:

```
"http://www.ex.com abc http://www.anotherex.com"
```

Should be replaced by:

```
"http://www.newex.com?old=http://www.ex.com ABC http://www.newex.com?old=http://www.anotherex.com"
```

I thought about using replaceAll, but I dont know exactly how to reuse the regex pattern in the replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like

```
String processed = yourString.replaceAll([ugly url regexp],"http://www.newex.com?old=$0")
```

$0 being a reference to the main capture group of the regexp. see the documentation for [Matcher.appendReplacement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29)

for a worthy regexp, you can have your pick from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163360/regular-expresion-to-match-urls-in-java) for example

Answer (score 1):

I would go about this by doing something like:

```
List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("regex here")
  .matcher(StringHere);
while (m.find()) {
allMatches.add(m.group());
}

for(String myMatch : allMatches)
{
  finalString = OriginalString.replace(myMatch, myNewString+myMatch);
}
```

I didn't test any of this, but it should give you an idea of how to approach it

Comment: String.replace() replaces all occurences of a given character with another character - you were probably aiming for replaceAll/replaceFirst? also, Strings being immutable, String.replace*() does not alter the string it was called on, but rather returns a new String.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the question, since I am looping over every match in the regex the .replace() should correctly replace each item. Good point about saving the return of the replace though. I updated my code to reflect that. Either way, your solution is more elagant/quicker and should be the selected answer!