# How to validate URL in java using regex?

Tags: java, regex, validation

I want to validate url started with `http/https/www/ftp` and checks for `/\` slashes and checks for `.com`,`.org` etc at the end of URL using regular expression. Is there any regex patttern for URL validation?

Comment: Why not just try to establish an [`URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) & connect to it?  Best test ever.

Comment: Duplicate? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: Refer this link:

[Regular expresion to match URLs in Java][1]

Hope it helps you.
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163360/regular-expresion-to-match-urls-in-java

Comment: Existing regular expression is not suited for me. That's y I have asked here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This works:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(@)?(href=')?(HREF=')?(HREF=\")?(href=\")?(http://)?[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-]+(\\.\\w[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-]+)+(/[#&\\n\\-=?\\+\\%/\\.\\w]+)?");  

    Matcher m = p.matcher("your url here");
```

Answer (score 8):

I am use the following code for that

```
String lRegex = "^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";
```

btw a search in google and you would find the solution by yourself.

Comment: it is not checking for www if I write www.abc.com

Comment: psisodia: "www" is not necessary in URL address

Comment: @Stefan Beike : Shall it will check for `192.168.67.90/mysite/page1.html` url ?