# Clickable URLs in TextView

Tags: android, textview, linkify

I can't figure out how to use `Linkify` for my TextView. I'm currently trying:

```
Linkify.addLinks(myTextView, Pattern.compile("^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]"), "http://");
```

I am using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163360/regular-expresion-to-match-urls-in-java) for my regex, which checks out [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).

Am I missing something that I have to do in order to have URLs in my `TextView` clickable?

Essentially, I am hoping to have my `TextView` show my URLs as clickable links and actually click through, just like iOS's `UITextView`s are able to by changing the `dataDetectorTypes` property to match the proper `UIDataDetectorType`.

Comment: try the other method from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable)

Comment: @vikki Thank you, however, I've already tried that one as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Linkfy there should be no need to write an own regex pattern for web urls, just use

```
 Linkify.addLinks(text, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

Comment: Potentially the fastest growth on an account? 1 > 26 nearly instantly.

Answer (score 3):

Use `android:autoLink="web"` in your layout XML for the `TextView` to handle `http`/`https`.

If you wish to continue using `Linkify`, be sure to do this after you have set the text in the `TextView`, not before.

Comment: I've tried setting it in Java using `myTextField.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);`, however, that doesn't effect it at all. Is the XML different? My `TextView` isn't in XML anywhere.

Comment: @RileyE: "Is the XML different?" -- yes. It's fewer characters. :-) Beyond that, though, I would have expected your code to have worked.

Comment: I would have figured that, as well. Thank you so much for the suggestion, though!