# Get Specific URL from the Text/String Using Java

Tags: java, string, url

I'm newbie to Java, I want to get all of the URL in the text below

```
WEBSITE1 https://localhost:8080/admin/index.php?page=home
WEBSITE2 https://192.168.0.3:8084/index.php
WEBSITE3 https://192.168.0.5:9090/controller/index.php?page=home
WEBSITE4 https://192.168.0.1:8080/home/index.php?page=forum
```

the result that I want is:

```
https://localhost:8080
https://192.168.0.3:8084
https://192.168.0.5
https://192.168.0.1:8080
```

I want to store it into the Linked List or Array too.
Can somebody teach me?
Thank You

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163360/regular-expresion-to-match-urls-in-java

Comment: @juniperi VERY bad idea, when you have [URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html)

Comment: @fge Second answer uses URI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple regexp to locate what's starting with `https?://` and then just extract this until the first `/`

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(https?://[^/]+)").matcher(//
        "WEBSITE1 https://localhost:8080/admin/index.php?page=home\r\n" + //
        "WEBSITE2 https://192.168.0.3:8084/index.php\r\n" + //
        "WEBSITE3 https://192.168.0.5:9090/controller/index.php?page=home\r\n" + //
        "WEBSITE4 https://192.168.0.1:8080/home/index.php?page=forum");
List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
    urls.add(m.group(1));
}
System.out.println(urls);
```

Now if you do want to get only the `WEBSITE.` part you will only have to change the regular expression `"(https?://[^/]+)"` with the following one: `"(.*?)\\s+https?"`. The rest of the code stays untouched.

Comment: thank you, and what if I want to get the list of website name?
for example, the result that I want:
website1
website2
website3
website4

thank you agan :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do this. I did one for you and you do the rest :)

```
try {
            ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
            URL aURL = new URL("https://localhost:8080/admin/index.php?page=home");
             System.out.println("protocol = " + aURL.getProtocol()+aURL.getHost()+aURL.getPort());
             urls.add(aURL.getProtocol()+aURL.getHost()+aURL.getPort());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the `line` represents a single line (probably in a loop):

```
//get the index of "https" in the string
int indexOfHTTPS= line.indexOf("https://");
//get the index of the first "/" after the "https"
int indexOfFirstSlashAfterHTTPS= line.indexOf("/", indexOfHTTPS + "https://".length());

//take a string between "https" and the first "/"
String url = line.substring(indexOfHTTPS, indexOfFirstSlashAfterHTTPS);
```

Later on, add this url to an `ArrayList<String>`:

```
ArrayList<String> urlList= new ArrayList<String>();
urlList.add(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the help of `URL class.`

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException { 

        String string ="https://192.168.0.5:9090/controller/index.php?page=home";
        URL url= new URL(string);
        String result ="https://"+url.getHost()+":"+url.getPort();
        System.out.println(result);
    }

Output :https://192.168.0.5:9090
```

Comment: That won't grab the port -- hence the interest of using `URI` instead. What is more, `URI` will never attempt to resolve hostnames

Answer (score 0):

You could either try to find the index of the protocol substring ("http[s]") in the Strings, or use a simple `Pattern` (only for matching the "website[0-9]" head, **not** to apply to the URLs).

Here's a solution with the `Pattern`.

```
String webSite1 = "WEBSITE1 https://localhost:8080/admin/index.php?page=home";
String webSite2 = "WEBSITE2 https://192.168.0.3:8084/index.php";
String webSite3 = "WEBSITE3 https://192.168.0.5:9090/controller/index.php?page=home";
String webSite4 = "WEBSITE4 https://192.168.0.1:8080/home/index.php?page=forum";
ArrayList<URI> uris = new ArrayList<URI>();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^website\\d+\\s+?(.+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher;
matcher = pattern.matcher(webSite1);
if (matcher.find()) {
    try {
        uris.add(new URI(matcher.group(1)));
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException use) {
        use.printStackTrace();
    }
}
matcher = pattern.matcher(webSite2);
if (matcher.find()) {
    try {
        uris.add(new URI(matcher.group(1)));
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException use) {
        use.printStackTrace();
    }
}
matcher = pattern.matcher(webSite3);
if (matcher.find()) {
    try {
        uris.add(new URI(matcher.group(1)));
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException use) {
        use.printStackTrace();
    }
}
matcher = pattern.matcher(webSite4);
if (matcher.find()) {
    try {
        uris.add(new URI(matcher.group(1)));
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException use) {
        use.printStackTrace();
    }
}
System.out.println(uris);
```

Output:

```
[https://localhost:8080/admin/index.php?page=home, https://192.168.0.3:8084/index.php, https://192.168.0.5:9090/controller/index.php?page=home, https://192.168.0.1:8080/home/index.php?page=forum]
```