# Java: RegEx to check for http links in a String

Tags: java, regex

I need to check if there are any http link in a string, but I don't figure it out yet how to do this. I know I can check if a link is a valid http link with something like the following

```
boolean valid = myString.matches("^(https?)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]");
```

I see it in this [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163360/regular-expresion-to-match-urls-in-java), it works if the string is just the link, without spaces and other words, but I want a regex to check for http links in a sentence, which could or not contains spaces and more words, I tried the next:

```
boolean valid = s.matches(".*\\s+^(https?)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|].*$")
```

But I don't get it, I don' really know much about regex, so I'd appreciate any help.

Thankz in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: No, not really, the regex is quite different, I don't want to extract any html tag links in source coder, rather http links in any sentence in plain text, quite diffetent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.*(https?)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|].*$
```

Translated:
 (Any characters) hyperlink (Any characters)

You can test it [here](http://regexpal.com/) with some strings of your own.