# Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to detect urls, which doesn't have protocol (fore example `google.com` and `www.google.com`)

The following code results the following error:

`Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`

```
String url = "www.google.com";
url.matches("^\\w+\\.\\w+")
```

Comment: With the code you posted, I don't get a compilation error.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Didn't test it, but I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Really good answer about Java url regex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163360/regular-expresion-to-match-urls-in-java) with examples or different types of matches. Just remove the part matching http,ftp part and it would work for you

Comment: the NSRegularExpression [Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says that \w is a valid character set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted. It compiles and runs fine. See it working here: http://ideone.com/Mtk3vG

However, the match seemed negative. To match it, try:

```
"^(\\w+\\.)?\\w+\\.\\w+$"
```

You will have to give us more surrounding code to point out what is wrong.

Comment: This error is displayed when i copy url.matches("^\\w+\\.\\w+") to eclipse "Expressions" in the debug perspective. your reg expression does not match for "google.com"

Comment: Oh, for google.com... I'll edit

Comment: Yes, indeed. I was too quick. :)