# Find URLs in String with Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I have String value that is txt (not html) that contains urls:

> Blabla http://www.example.com/foo1/ blabla
>   http://www.example.com/foo2/ blabla...

I need to grab all these urls from the string using Jsoup.

Is it possible?

Comment: You say you want to parse this string with jsoup? Or is it a parse result from jsoup?

Comment: Parse such string as I mentioned - it is txt string, not HTML, so I cannot use finding hrefs by tag name "a".

Comment: Use RE : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163360/regular-expresion-to-match-urls-in-java

Comment: Because I use Jsoup for parsing HTML pages, I've wanted to avoid to use own regular while parsing TXT strings. Thanks instead.

Comment: can't you grab all as html and regex out what you need.

Answer (score 0):

No, Jsoup won't do this for you.  Jsoup parses HTML tags, not arbitrary strings.

If you had an HTML document containing a bunch of link tags (`<a href="http://example.com/page.html>link text</a>`), you could use Jsoup to parse the tags and extract the `href` attribute.

If you just have a string with some links, you probably want to use [regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163360/regular-expresion-to-match-urls-in-java?lq=1), as suggested in a comment by PeterMmm.