# Android java - Regex to check whether the url starts with https or http

Tags: java, android

I am getting some `urls` from server that contains some images. Some urls start with `http` and some start with `https`. I need to check if the url string contain `http`, then put an `s` in that string after `p`, and if it contains `https` then do nothing.

Comment: Please post what did you try so far.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your needs. What have you tried so far and how does it fail?

Comment: check this url :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163360/regular-expresion-to-match-urls-in-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (urlString.startsWith("http://")) {
    urlString = urlString.replaceFirst("http", "https");
}
```