# Java regex from pdf file read

Tags: java, regex, pdf

I have a java project which it will read text from pdf files. The pdf contain tabular format which will contain breakline if the column span the text content. 
Eg: "This is www.google.com" become "This is www.goog/nle.com" (spanned to next line).  I will need to extract this text out and process it using domain regex pattern. It won't get a proper "www.google.com" if it spanned. 
I couldn't replace the "/n" as I might have scenario eg: "This is an This is www.google.com/nwww.yahoo.com".

*This pdf file is converted from a docx which if java read from docx it is getting www.google.com fine without the breakline issue. It happen only in pdf.

Any thought? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could remove all line-breaks first and the apply a regex like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163360/regular-expression-to-match-urls-in-java) to find all URLs.

Comment: You shouldn't have downvoted me. Please read my question properly as I wouldn't ask if I can remove the breakline. :)

Comment: I voted your question neither up nor down. However: Solving this problem with a regular expression is not a good way, because the expression might become very complicated and not maintainable. Just try out simple expression, e.g. on this site: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx