# Newbie with regex

Tags: java, regex

I have to build smth with URL, but only with valid google play links. I will get a link from user and want to check it before connect to it. If i have a Google Play link like this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com....
I want to match it with regex and method matches (or should I just use method contains?) If link contains play.google.com - it's true and then do some actions. If false - throw new exception.

I tried with

```
\\. + play.google. + \\.
```

but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to match URLs in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163360/regular-expression-to-match-urls-in-java)

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1):

\. matches a literal, actual dot. You want the actual dot:

```
Pattern.compile("^.*play\\.google\\..*$");
```

However, you *do not want to do this* – here is a URL that will match: `https://www.hacker.ru/hahaThisWillMatch?irrelevant=play.google`

Put the URI into the `java.net.URI` class, and ask it what the server is, as well as the port, and the protocol. The port needs to be non-existent, the protocol needs to be https, and the server needs to be `play.google.com`, I'm not sure what other google domains you're looking for, but if you are, check against them all, don't try to use a regexp, because there are thousands of top level domains and google didn't register 'google' in literally *ALL* of them.