# How to strip down a string to the first duplicate?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have converted a few web pages into string and the string contains these lines(along with other code):

```
<div class="r"><a href="https://www.apple.com/ca/"
<div class="r"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/ca/"
<div class="r"><a href="https://www.utorrent.com/ca/"
```

but I just want to strip out the link inside the first line(`https://www.apple.com/ca/`) and ignore the rest of the HTML and the code. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way:

```
String url = input.replaceAll("(?s).*?href=\"(.*?)\".*", "$1");
```

Key points of why this works:

- regex matches the whole input, but captures the target. The replacement is the capture (group #1). This approach effectively *extracts* the target
- `(?s)` means “dot matches newline”
- `.*?` is *reluctantly* (as *little* input as possible) matches up to “href"”
- `(.*?)` capture (reluctantly) everything up to “"”
- `.*` *greedily* (as *much* as possible) matches the rest (thanks to `(?s)` above)
- replacement is `$1` - the first (and only) group in the match

Comment: Excuse my brevity but how did you do that??

Comment: @Drcola see edited answer for explanation

Answer (score 1):

Using the regex mentioned in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/163398/10819573), given below is the solution using the [Java regex API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "<div class=\"r\"><a href=\"https://www.apple.com/ca/\">Hello</a>\n"
                + "<div class=\"r\"><a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/ca/\">Hello</a>\n"
                + "<div class=\"r\"><a href=\"https://www.utorrent.com/ca/\">Hello</a>";
        String regex = "\\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
https://www.apple.com/ca/
https://www.facebook.com/ca/
https://www.utorrent.com/ca/
```

Comment: Hey sir, this is no good because the code is set up to look for the first visible url in the string. The problem is, I want the first URL after the line `<div class="r"><a href="`, not the first url in the entire HTML

Comment: This doesn’t actually answer the question, which was to get *the first* URL *only*. You could add a `break` to the loop, but it sure is a lot of code.